# What speed does the A4 in the iPhone 4 run at?

Tags: iphone

Apple made a big deal about the iPad's A4 running at 1GHz, but they've never said how fast the iPhone 4's processor is. In the teardown, iFixit mentions that the iPhone 4 uses an A4 but never gives a clock speed. Has anyone been able to find out how fast it actually is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MacRumors](http://www.macrumors.com/2010/06/23/iphone-4-is-faster-than-3gs-and-slower-than-ipad-in-early-benchmarks/) and [some German source](http://www.ipad-tipps.de/ipad-schneller-als-iphone-4/) the iPhone 4 is somewhat slower than the iPad, but still significantly faster than the iPhone 3GS. I guess that its A4 CPU is clocked at about 750 - 850 MHz.

Comment: +1. Also, it actually has more RAM than the iPad too. (512 vs 256)

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone 4 is based on the same processor that is seen in the iPad and has a clock speed of 1Ghz.

The iPhone 4 also has 512mb of RAM which is double that of the 3GS and although never officially announced also double that of the iPad.

Comment: its the same processor, but its not clocked at 1GHz like the iPad.

Comment: -1. It's clearly not 1 GHz (see the benchmarks). Apple has a tradition of underclocking the iPhone's CPU since the very first generation.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not confirmed, most sources claim that the A4 in the iPhone 4 is the same processor that runs the iPad, clocking in at 1ghz as you suggested.